How to get a graph from file *.msagl?
I'm writing application on Winforms C# and using library MSAGL to display graph's.
Now I'm stuck at loading graph's from file *.msagl.
Here is my code for processing the loaded file:
private void loadGraphToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            return;
        }

        string fileName = openFileDialog.FileName;
        string file = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

        Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        using (Stream stream = fileText.ToStream(encoding))
        {
            GraphReader graphReader = new GraphReader(stream);//err1
            graph = graphReader.Read();//err2
        }

        AppValues.DrawGraph(gGraphviewer,graph,pnlGraphDisplay);          
        UpdateProperties();
        graphIsInitialized();
}

How can I get a graph (variable with type Microsft.Msagl.Drawing.Graph) from this file to draw it on gGraphViewer (type GViewer)?
Function DrawGraph:
public static void DrawGraph(GViewer gViewer,Graph graph,Panel panel)
{
    gViewer.Graph = graph;
    gViewer.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    panel.Controls.Add(gViewer);
    gViewer.OutsideAreaBrush = System.Drawing.Brushes.White;  
    gViewer.ToolBarIsVisible = false;  
}

PS: I know about load button on toolbar of GViewer, but can't find how to call it function.
PPS: Get two errors: err1 - CS1729, err2 - CS1061. But in official repository on githhub it has be parameter of constructor and method of class.

The GraphReader's class constructor is internal (https://github.com/microsoft/automatic-graph-layout/blob/b199357c4aa4001ff19263e3e765b7cca53aebc1/GraphLayout/Drawing/GraphReader.cs#L29). You probably want to use Graph.ReadFromStream() (https://github.com/microsoft/automatic-graph-layout/blob/b199357c4aa4001ff19263e3e765b7cca53aebc1/GraphLayout/Drawing/Graph.cs#L603)

Thank you very much. This is what I was looking for)
